# PHP trimming spaces unnecessarily?

Tags: php, string, character, trim

Let's say I have a variable `$foo`:

```
$foo = "   a          a             blablabla          a        a";
```

But when I do `var_dump($foo)` the following gets outputted:

```
string(57) " a a blablabla a a"
```

It's like the length (57 in this case) it's correct and it counts the spaces, but it doesn't display them.
How can I display the *full* string, including the multiple spaces in between the other characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `<pre>` tag the text appears in the brower as you typed it. Couple of links:

- http://www.tizag.com/htmlT/htmlpre.php
- http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/linepar/_PRE.html

You could also replace spaces with non breaking space `&nbsp;`.

Web browsers ignore a lot white space in the code which is nice. Otherwise we wouldn't be able to intend our source code or use newlines much...

Comment: Thanks! I did wonder why browsers omit indentation, now it makes sense. The `<pre>` tag works perfectly

Answer (score 1):

Are you by any chance doing this in a browser. If so you need to do this.

```
<pre>
<?php echo var_dump($foo); ?>
</pre>
```

Because I just tried in command line and I get the output with spaces. Browsers don't handle multiple spaces and they trim them down. If you want a browser to handle multiple spaces you have to use the output inside a `<pre>` tag or use `&nbsp;` instead of spaces.

Answer (score 0):

something like `echo str_replace(' ', '&nbsp;',$test);`